# Use regex to allow for alphabetic characters, hypens, underscores, spaces, and numbers

Tags: laravel, validation

I would like to validate using Laravel for a unique situation. The field I am authorizing is the name of a book. So it can have alphabetic characters, numeric characters, spaces, and hypens/underscores/any other key. The only thing I don't want it to have is spaces at the beginning, before you enter any key. So the name can't be " L", notice the space, whereas "L L L" is completely acceptable. Could anyone help me in this situation?

So far I got a regex validation as such:

```
regex:[a-z{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}]
```

I'm unsure how to include the other restrictions.

Comment: Laravel 5.4 adds a middleware just for that purpose `Trim Strings Middleware` here is the class `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings` so don't worry about exra spaces ;)

Comment: Yea I attempted to use alpha_num as a validation method, but then when I use spaces such as "L L L", it says there is an error. :/

Comment: Try using this in your validation rules `'regex:/^[\w-]*$/'` !

Comment: @Maraboc no luck :/ it doesn't allow for me to add spaces in between. If I write "L L L", it throws an error.

Comment: Just add `\s` ==> `'regex:/^[\s\w-]*$/'` :)

Comment: Thanks @Maraboc, it worked for spaces perfectly! Could you please tell me how I would allow for periods, commas, backslashes, and brackets? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150332/discussion-between-maraboc-and-muhammad).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **Short answer :**

For alpha_num with spaces use this regEx :

```
'regex:/^[\s\w-]*$/'
```

- **Bit longer one :)**

Here is some defined bolcks of regEx :

```
^           ==>  The circumflex symbol marks the beginning of a pattern, although in some cases it can be omitted
$           ==>  Same as with the circumflex symbol, the dollar sign marks the end of a search pattern
.           ==>  The period matches any single character
?           ==>  It will match the preceding pattern zero or one times
+           ==>  It will match the preceding pattern one or more times
*           ==>  It will match the preceding pattern zero or more times
|           ==>  Boolean OR
–           ==>  Matches a range of elements
()          ==>  Groups a different pattern elements together
[]          ==>  Matches any single character between the square brackets
{min, max}  ==>  It is used to match exact character counts
\d          ==>  Matches any single digit
\D          ==>  Matches any single non digit character
\w          ==>  Matches any alpha numeric character including underscore (_)
\W          ==>  Matches any non alpha numeric character excluding the underscore character
\s          ==>  Matches whitespace character
```

And if you want to add some other chars all you should do is add it to the `[]` block.

For example if you want allow the `,` ==> `'regex:/^[\s\w-,]*$/'`.

PS : One more thing if you want a setial char such us \ * or . you must escape them like this \ * .

For `*` ==> `'regex:/^[\s\w-,\*]*$/'`

Answer (score 0):

check this pattern:

```
<?php

$pattern = '/^(?=[^ ])[A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+$/';
$test = ' L';

if (preg_match($pattern, $test)) {
    echo 'matched';
} else {
     echo 'does not match';   
}

?>
```